# Linq expression to validate if list is ordered ascending or descending

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `IEnumerable<DateTime>` var that I need to validate if it is sorted ascendingly or descendingly.

I can do this using a for loop but is there a way to do this using LINQ expression?

Comment: you want to sort it, or check of it is sorted or not?

Comment: Check if it is sorted ascendingly or descendingly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var orderedByAsc = input.OrderBy(d => d);
if (input.SequenceEqual(orderedByAsc))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ordered by Asc");
    return;
}

var orderedByDsc = input.OrderByDescending(d => d);
if (input.SequenceEqual(orderedByDsc))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ordered by Dsc");
    return;
}

Console.WriteLine("not sorted");
```

Comment: This is good but it can be done more easily if the list is guaranteed to be either one or the other.

Comment: The problem with this is that the cost of checking if it's sorted is more than the cost of sorting in the first place.

Comment: @decPL Why? You can check if it's sorted (asc/desc) in `O(n)`.

Comment: @Daniel Exactly - you can, but the answer above does the sort first (`O(n log n)`) and comparison afterwards (`O(n)`), that's why I've pointed it's strictly worse than sorting in the first place. That being said, an `O(n)` LINQ solution is not easy to read (see my answer), so I personally wouldn't use LINQ at all here.

Answer (score 11):

Ascending:

```
myEnumerable.Zip(myEnumerable.Skip(1), (curr, next) => curr <= next).All(x => x);
```

Descending:

```
myEnumerable.Zip(myEnumerable.Skip(1), (curr, next) => curr >= next).All(x => x);
```

But use a loop, LINQ is not a magic solution to everything.

Answer (score 4):

LINQ extensions. Good candidates to MoreLinq library:

```
public static bool IsOrdered<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    return source.IsOrdered(OrderByDirection.Ascending, comparer);
}

public static bool IsOrdered<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, OrderByDirection direction, IComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    }

    if (comparer == null)
    {
        comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
    }

    int d = direction == OrderByDirection.Ascending ? 1 : -1;

    Func<T, T, int> compareFunc= (i1, i2) => d * comparer.Compare(i1, i2);
    return IsOrderedImpl(source, compareFunc);
}

public static bool IsOrdered<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, int> compareFunc)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    }
    if (compareFunc == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(compareFunc));
    }

    return IsOrderedImpl(source, compareFunc);
}

private static bool IsOrderedImpl<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, int> compareFunc)
{
    T prevItem = default(T);
    int i = 0;
    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            prevItem = item;
        }
        else
        {
            if (compareFunc(prevItem, item) > 0)
            {
                return false;
            }

            prevItem = item;
        }

        ++i;
    }

    return true;
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestIsOrdered01()
{
    Assert.IsTrue(Enumerable.Range(1, 10).IsOrdered());
    Assert.IsFalse(Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Reverse().IsOrdered());
    Assert.IsTrue(Enumerable.Range(1, 10).IsOrdered(OrderByDirection.Ascending));
    Assert.IsFalse(Enumerable.Range(1, 10).IsOrdered(OrderByDirection.Descending));
    Assert.IsFalse(Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Reverse().IsOrdered(OrderByDirection.Ascending));
    Assert.IsTrue(Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Reverse().IsOrdered(OrderByDirection.Descending));
}
```

Comment: I like the foreach loop in IsOrderedImpl which is more elegant than a for (i=1; i<count; i++) solution.

Comment: @huha , it is not just "more elegant". It is simply the only correct way since you can't get the `count` from and then iterate over IEnumerable without making redundant (may be very expensive in some cases) second enumeration.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure about that the list is ordered then you can simply compare the lists first and last elements to see if it is in ascending or descending order.

Comment: I said 'if you are sure about that the list is ordered'. The example of yours is not ordered. So we cannot talk about the order direction here can we?

Comment: OP exactly says this: 'it is sorted ascendingly or descendingly'. knows that it is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

This may be over-engineered but is hopefully educational and of some use nonetheless!

```
public enum SortedState
{
    NoValues,
    Undecided,
    Ascending,
    Descending,
    Mixture
};

public class AscOrDescHelper<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    SortedState state;
    T lastValue;
    bool uniqueValues;

    public AscOrDescHelper()
    {
        state = SortedState.NoValues;
        uniqueValues = true;    // tentative assumption
    }

    public AscOrDescHelper<T> ProcessNextValue(T next)
    {
        switch (state)
        {
            case SortedState.NoValues:
                state = SortedState.Undecided;
                break;
            case SortedState.Undecided:
            case SortedState.Ascending:
            case SortedState.Descending:
                int cmp = next.CompareTo(lastValue);
                switch (state)
                {
                    case SortedState.Undecided:
                        if (cmp > 0)
                        {
                            state = SortedState.Ascending;
                        }
                        else if (cmp < 0)
                        {
                            state = SortedState.Descending;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            uniqueValues = false;
                        }
                        break;
                    case SortedState.Ascending:
                        if (cmp < 0)
                        {
                            state = SortedState.Mixture;
                        }
                        else if (cmp == 0)
                        {
                            // Not unique
                            uniqueValues = false;
                        }
                        break;
                    case SortedState.Descending:
                        if (cmp > 0)
                        {
                            state = SortedState.Mixture;
                        }
                        else if (cmp == 0)
                        {
                            // Not unique
                            uniqueValues = false;
                        }
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }

        lastValue = next;

        return this;
    }

    public SortedState State()
    {
        return state;
    }

    public bool? Unique()
    {
        return state == SortedState.Mixture ? (bool?)null : uniqueValues;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format(
            "{0} ({1})",
            State(),
            Unique().HasValue ? (Unique().Value ? "unique" : "not unique")
                : "unknown uniqueness");
    }
};

static void CheckIfSorted<T>(IEnumerable<T> values) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        values.Aggregate(
            new AscOrDescHelper<T>(),
            (last, next) => last.ProcessNextValue(next)));
}

static void Main()
{
    CheckIfSorted(new string[]{ "amy", "kate", "sally" });
    CheckIfSorted(new int[]{ 7, 5, 5 });
    CheckIfSorted(new int[]{ 2, 3, 1 });
    // Gives:
    //   Ascending (unique)
    //   Descending (not unique)
    //   Mixture (unknown uniqueness)
}
```

I am a C# beginner, so constructive advice is welcome ;)