# c# how to check if list of Items are in Alphabetical order or not

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have list of 10 Iwebelements . i've stored their text into another list(As i just need to check that all 10 are in Alphabetical Order)

Can any one please tell me how to do that .

(Below code will get the list of all elements and with Foreach i'm getting their text and adding them into X list)

```
 IList<IWebElement> otherSports = Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".sports-buttons-container .other-sport .sport-name"));
        List<string> x = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in otherSports)
        {
            string btnText = item.Text.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");
            x.Add(item.Text.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, ""));
        }
```

Note:- I dont want to sort the list . I just want to see if all items in List X is in Alphabetical order.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq expression to validate if list is ordered ascending or descending](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23562150/linq-expression-to-validate-if-list-is-ordered-ascending-or-descending)

Comment: It mostly is a duplicate, but the accepted answer is very inefficient.  You don't need to sort a list to find out if it is sorted, you just need to go through the list and check that each new value is greater than the last

Comment: @EuanSmith i agree with you as i dont want to do sorting . So as you suggested can you please tell me how can i do each new value is greater than the last?

Comment: look below, while we've been adding comments somebody has added an answer that, I think, does what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like that

```
 [TestMethod]
 public void TestOrder()
 {
     IList<IWebElement> otherSports = Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".sports-buttons-container .other-sport .sport-name"));
     var x = otherSports.Select(item=>item.Text.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, ""))
     var sorted = new List<string>();
     sorted.AddRange(x.OrderBy(o=>o));
     Assert.IsTrue(x.SequenceEqual(sorted));
 }
```

So this method will fail untill list x list is ordered alphabetically

Comment: :- I dont want to order the list as whatever it is i just want to make sure that is in the alpha. Order. However i did liked the idea of putting assert .

Comment: @vic well how do you want check if the are in alphabetic order then? you want to check only first letter?

Comment: Biyachat :- I'm getting all the items in X list and i dont want to touch their order . I just want to see if all those items from X lists are in Alphabetical Order.

Comment: Also can you please explain me what does below line will do (I'm not good with Linq)

   sorted.AddRange(x.OrderBy(o => o));

Comment: @vic that is why i am not touching x. I have second array sorted. and line order with sorted.AddRange means that i am creating new array which will be sorted.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `StringComparer.Ordinal` to check if two strings are in alphabetical order.

```
var alphabetical = true;
for (int i = 0; i < x.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if (StringComparer.Ordinal.Compare(x[i], x[i + 1]) > 0)
    {
        alphabetical = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

An alternative solution if you prefer LINQ(but less readable, IMO)

```
var alphabetical = !x.Where((s, n) => n < x.Count - 1 && StringComparer.Ordinal.Compare(x[n], x[n + 1]) > 0).Any();
```

**EDIT** since you are generating the list your self, you can add solution 1 into your code when the list is created, that's more efficient.

```
IList<IWebElement> otherSports = Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".sports-buttons-container .other-sport .sport-name"));
List<string> x = new List<string>();
var alphabetical = true;
string previous = null;

foreach (var item in otherSports)
{
    string btnText = item.Text.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");
    var current = item.Text.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");
    x.Add(current);

    if (previous != null && StringComparer.Ordinal.Compare(previous,current) > 0)
    {
        alphabetical = false;
    }
    previous = current;
}
```